# input:checked on specific class only

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently doing works on radio button, I wanted to changed the background when the radio button is checked

```
.input:checked + label {
    transition: .5s;
    background: #3498db !important;
    color: white !important;

}
```

I did was this, but the other radio button will have background. I just want to add the background to a specific class only.

I also tried

```
.radio-button-popup input:checked + label {
    transition: .5s;
    background: #3498db !important;
    color: white !important;

}
```

But it didn't work. this is how my radio button structure is.

```
<div class="input-group-radio">
    <input type="radio" style="display:none;" name="option-radio-test" class="radio-button-popup" value="test" id="test1">
    <label style=" font-weight: normal !important; padding: 2% !important; border-radius: 5px;" for="test1" class=" input-group-label">Test Radio</label>
</div>
```

I only want the background on this specific set of radio button in radio button's class "radio-button-popup".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nearly there. Your only mistake is to use the `input` selector after you allready selected the input.

```css
.radio-button-popup:checked + label {
    transition: .5s;
    background: #3498db !important;
    color: white !important;

}
```

```html
<div class="input-group-radio">
    <input type="radio" style="display:none;" name="option-radio-test" class="radio-button-popup" value="test" id="test1">
    <label style=" font-weight: normal !important; padding: 2% !important; border-radius: 5px;" for="test1" class=" input-group-label">Test Radio</label>
</div>
```